# Как понизить/откатить версию jupyter lab?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, markdown

Увидел обнову от jupyter lab, решил обновиться, обновился до версии 4.0.5 после этого стали плохо работать ячейки markdown (не работает форматирование текста), как откатить версию? или удалить полностью и установить конкретную версию (а не самую новую)

Comment: Смотря как устанавливали. Если через pip, то `pip install --update jupyterlab==4.0.0` (4.0.0 заменяете на нужную версию). Нужно указывать, как именно устанавливали, а то знаем мы вас датасатанистов с анакондой.

Comment: Спасибо, это то что нужно было, я этот же метод нашел на англоязычном форуме. Благодарю. Анакондой не пользуюсь, устанавливал через командную строку:)